# Where is the link between NUMA code for writing a page and the rest of Linux swap

Tags: linux, memory-management, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, numa

So, for normal pages in Linux `try_to_unmap` creates a swap entry for a particular page and then `pageout` handles writing it to the swap space by calling `mapping->a_ops->writepage` on it. Now, `shrink_page_list` connects the pieces together.

For NUMA pages on the other hand `try_to_unmap` creates a NUMA migration entry for a particular page, but I do not see where in the code it is actually written out and where in the code things are glued together.

Anyone knows the link?

Thanks.

Comment: A lot of stuff in VM subsystem happens in page fault handlers. If you see some simplistic code which supposedly leads to complex behavior, then this behavior will be somehow triggered in page fault processing pipe line.

Comment: Can you be a little bit more specific please?